# How to display rows that don't meet criteria

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two linked tables:

```
    Case_Table:                 Case_Clients
                                Client_ID (int, identity)
    Case_ID (int, identity) --- Case_ID (int)
    Conference_ID (int)         Relationship_ID (int)
    Other Stuff
```

Below is the SQL statement to list all records that has a head of household:

```
    SELECT Case_Table.Case_ID, 
           Case_Table.Conference_ID, 
           Case_Clients.Client_ID, 
           Case_Clients.Relationship_ID
    FROM   Case_Clients INNER JOIN
           Case_Table ON Case_Clients.Case_ID = Case_Table.Case_ID
    WHERE  (Case_Clients.Relationship_ID = 1)
```

The company requires that each case has a head of household, and we have taken steps to enforce this, but we still have the existing cases that do not have a head of household.  I know that I have over 100 cases without a Head of Household (Relationship_ID = 1).

Moving on...  what I am trying to do is to list the Conference_ID and Case_ID for each record in Case_Table that does not have a head of household in Case_Clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT IN` to retrieve any records in `CaseTable` that don't have records in `Case_Clients` where `RelationshipID = 1` (assuming that is the head-of-household record).

```
SELECT Case_Table.Case_ID, Case_Table.ConferenceID
FROM Case_Table
WHERE CaseTable.Case_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT Case_ID 
    FROM Case_Clients 
    WHERE RelationshipID = 1
)
```

Comment: This did the trick, I think.  And looking at it and seeing that the solution is so simple is enough to make me feel somewhat embarrassed.   Thanks for the quick solution.